# How to show a cell value based on a specific date in excel

Tags: excel

I'm fairly new to Excel, and I'm currently trying to build a workbook for personal finance. I have a breakdown of a specific account entered into excel so I can see the estimated/projected balance of the account on any given date.

***Here is an example of how the data is entered in Sheet1***
[image]

```
A1 01/01/18 - B1 $1

A2 02/01/18 - B2 $2

A3 03/01/18 - B3 $3

A4 04/01/18 - B4 $4

A5 05/01/18 - B5 $5
```

I'm trying to make a separate sheet (sheet2) in the workbook where I can manually type a date into a specific cell (A1 below), and the account balance will populate in another cell on this sheet (A2 below) based on the information in Sheet1.

***For example:***
[image]

A1 4/1/18 - B1 $4

I have been puzzling over this for weeks, and nothing I've tried has worked. I'd love any advice you can offer!

Thanks,
CSR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following both formula will do that. Put formula in `Sheet2 -- B1` Cell.

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet1!$A$1:$B$9,2,FALSE)

=INDEX(Sheet1!$A$1:$B$9,MATCH(A2,Sheet1!$A$1:$A$9,0),2)
```

Comment: You can use any one.

Comment: Thank you so much! The INDEX/MATCH option worked perfectly.

Comment: @CSR If you found it working, then you should accept my answer. Tick it at green.